# Manipulating DataSets

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

I'm having trouble manipulating/navigating a DataSet, which I'm pulling in as a automatically generated XML file.  My goal is to put certain nodes into columns in a SQL table.

my XML

```
<root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:mix="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/mix/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" xmlns:rep="internal" xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0">
      <submission name="entry0">
            <entry name="firstName">Name</entry> 
            <entry name="School">The University of College</entry> 
            <entry name="ExpectedYearofEntry">2019</entry> 
            <entry name="mailingAddress">Some st</entry> 
      </submission>
      <submission name..........
</root>
```

I'm trying this:

```
string xmlFile = @"xml.xml";

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
DataTable table = dataSet.Tables["entry"];
IEnumerable<DataRow> row = table.AsEnumerable();
```

When I break I can see the data in row; that is, `ItemArray` 0 contains the firstName and 'Name'.  But I can't figure out how to pull this data from row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like **SqlBulkCopy** to efficiently insert all those rows into a table. You will have to do this for each Table in the DataSet though.

Good example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx
Once you have a DataTable to insert.

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set target table
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Customers";

            //Map the DataTable columns with the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "CustomerId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Country", "Country");
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```